# Incase of page reload while an ongoing query from laravel to mysql is ongoing does it stop the whole execution

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Incase of a page reload,
And say for instance I have an `ajax` request to a `laravel` application wanting to fetch about one million records and I am working with `mysql` but I due to this bulk, I decide to reload the page.

Architecture wise, does this halt the execution of this query by mysql or will it continue executing in the background?

Or once the connection is cut to the laravel application, does laravel as well cut the connection to the database as well.

Comment: This is a [good read](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php). To the best of my knowledge, Laravel doesn't do anything extra special to change this.

Comment: This is not a coding question, but about how the browser/server handles a lost connection. SO is not the correct platform for this. As Chris Haas commented, Laravel does not do anything for this, but in theory the request is terminated when you reload.

Comment: @GertB., just to be clear, the browser will terminate the request, but PHP will probably continue executing until a halt is received, either by naturally reaching the end of the script, someone calling `exit` or similar, or a timeout is reached. And whatever PHP is doing, including talking to the database, will continue, too. There is also `ignore_user_abort` which says "PHP will not detect that the user has aborted the connection until an attempt is made to send information to the client"